# Issue with changing class names using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change the background color of the currently clicked on tab in my navigation menu.  Then when I click a different tab, I want the old one to change back to the original background color.  I've seen this tons of places, but every tutorial I follow hasn't worked for me.

Here is the html code I have for the navigation. Basically, I want to change the class "member_nav" to "member_nav_clicked" and then back to "member_nav" when a different tab is clicked.

```
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:nav1(); load_video('6')">Nav 1</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:nav2(); load_video('2')">Nav 2</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:nav3(); load_video('4')">Nav 3</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:nav4(); load_video('5')">nav 4</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:nav5(); load_video('3')">Nav 5</a>
</div>
```

I'm not going to include any of the javascript functions I've tried, since none of it was working.

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer if you DO include the code you tried. We know it's not working - that's why you're here! That gives people something to fix, rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: So what does all the inline javascript do, and are you clicking the DIV's or the anchors, it's not the same thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S4F9M/

Comment: I've clicked both the divs and the anchor sections, and neither was changing it.  The javascript changes the content on the page.

Comment: @JonB and other downvoters, sorry i was using SO from my mobile, so i posted that as an answer by mistake. i was making that as a comment. Removed that answer.

Comment: Thanks Adeneo.  Do I need to put that js code in the header or at the bottom of the page?  What is the best practice?

Comment: Adeneo, I just put that in the <head> section and it didn't work.  It looks right, but I'm just not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Wrap it in document ready and put in the head, or put it right before `</body>`

Comment: Am I not supposed to put it in the <script> tag in the head?  Should it just be outside the main script area, or do I just put it in with the rest of the javascript?

Comment: I recommend reading Karl Groves' [Links are not buttons. Neither are DIVs and SPANs](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/) which won't teach you the necessary javascript but does bring up some great considerations. In particular, after reading the section _A link with a crappy (or missing) href isn’t a button_ I will never use `href=#` again. I do things like `<a href="#nav1">Nav 1</a>` — then you can even use the fragment identifier to pick which tab to show initially, and it can be bookmarked.

Comment: NM, silly question, I put it in the main script.  Wrapped in document ready.  Nothing is happening when I click the divs...

Comment: OK Stephen, I will check out that book.  This is super frustrating.  Trying a ton of solutions that everyone says works, and it's just not working.  I've checked my code a ton of times over the past four hours.  I guess I'll start a new page and try it in there, something must be interfering.

Comment: @adeneo I input my css into your jsfiddle and it looks the way I'd want it to look.  Is it possible that the onclick within the anchor tab is creating a conflict?  If that's not it, it must be something else in the code...or I'm not placing the javascript in the correct place.  I put it in the head within a javascript tag.

Comment: I've updated a copy of [adeneo's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4F9M/3/) to put the script in with the HTML. It would usually go in the `<head>` not in the body; or I _always_ put that sort of thing in a separate `.js` file that is linked in from the page.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen P, I put that on my page, and it isn't working.  I guess there is something wrong with my div structure, maybe it's not viewing them as siblings or something.  Arg.

Comment: So I found out that my site isn't calling in the specific stylesheet where the css rules are that are related to this.  What's odd, is that the page still displays as if that stylesheet is being called in. But I just checked, and it's not called in directly.  When I use firebug though, it references that stylesheet all over.  How is it accessing the stylesheet if it's not being called in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `active` class, then on a click event find the currently active element and remove the `active` class with `$('.active').removeClass('active')` after this set the `active` class to the clicked element `$(this).addClass('active')`.

@adeneo's anwser in the comments is actually better.

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is some jQuery 101... i suggest you read up on the basics. I set up a jsFiddle for you, and i hope you wont just copy paste it but also try to learn something from it.

You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wUpYh/1/

The code:

```
 $('a').on('click', function(){
            $('.member_nav_clicked').removeClass('member_nav_clicked').addClass('member_nav');       
            $(this).closest('.member_nav').removeClass('member_nav').addClass('member_nav_clicked');
        });
```

So what happens is, i remove the member_nav class and add the clicked class. The line above it will take care of the previous clicked item. When an element has the active class, it will be removed before asigning it to the new clicked element.

But to be honest, a nicer way of doing this, would be to assign an active class and leave the normal class as it is. Like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
                $('.member_nav_clicked').removeClass('member_nav_clicked');       
                $(this).closest('.member_nav').addClass('member_nav_clicked');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried implementing this and it didn't work for me.  I understand why it should work, but every solution I've found on here isn't getting it done in my case.  Been trying for over four hours.